# Decimal output needed when dividing integers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 input int values that need do be divided and sen back as a string with 6 decimals.

```
int a = 240
int b = 1440.
```

I want to divide them and send back a text string with `0,166667`

I have tried many code examples but none have worked.

Comment: An `int` division always yields an `int` result. You need to make sure you use a floating point division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert at least one to a decimal value:

```
double result = (double)a / b;
```

or

```
decimal result = (decimal)a / b;
```

On "decimal vs. double" see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when) question.